# Updating Thread progress on the Command Line

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use threads to show a progress bar on the CLI in java while doing a long operation (generating md5sums for a batch of large files).

I've written a bit of code, and it works, but I'd like to know if I'm using threads correctly as I'm pretty new to this.

I have two class files, `ProgressThreadTest.java` and `CountToABillion.java`

CountToABillion.java:

```
public class CountToABillion implements Runnable {

    double count = 0;

    public void echoCount() {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        for (double x=0;x<1000000000;x++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count = x;
            echoCount();
        }       
    }   
}
```

ProgressThreadTest.java:

```
public class ProgressThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread doCount=new Thread(new CountToABillion());
        doCount.start();
    }   
}
```

It works as expected and counts upwards on the command line.

Anyone have any comments on whether or not this is a good way to do threads?

Also, because I am updating the progress in the counting loop, it will update every 10ms. How would I change the code to only output the count once every second?

Comment: that for loop will cycle work for a month.

Comment: why do you need threads for updating progress on CLI?

Comment: You could use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) or [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to print your progress periodically.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen partially so I can learn how to use threads, and partially so I can choose how often to update the progress when generating the md5sums (will be running remotely sometimes so don't want to update the cli a million times per second). How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: @MichaelLang I don't know how to. Can you write an answer using either of those please?

Comment: to actually be productive with your threads , see how java.util.concurrent works and learn up on different patterns of thread usage. Ie. best way is probably to have one thread print out progress, have a queue full of work , then have a pool of threads pull work from that queue and do it.

Comment: @localhost I've posted a modified version of your example using `javax.swing.Timer` in the answers below.

Comment: @MichaelLang Thanks for your answer. Would it be stretching the friendship too much to ask for an example using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? I think that's what I'd rather learn so I can use those threads to do the md5 generation.

Comment: @localhost I've edited my answer with such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `javax.swing.Timer` is probably the easier solution:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CountToABillion implements Runnable {

    double count = 0;
    Timer progressTimer;

    public void echoCount() {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                echoCount();
            }
        });
        progressTimer.setRepeats(true);
        progressTimer.start();

        for (double x=0;x<1000000000;x++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count = x;
        }
        progressTimer.stop();
    }
}
```

Using `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is the better and more scalable solution:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CountToABillion implements Runnable {

    double count = 0;
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    public void echoCount() {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                echoCount();
            }
        };
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (double x=0;x<1000000000;x++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count = x;
        }
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't really understand `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` yet, but I'll learn it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void run() {     
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        count = i;

        if(i % 100 == 0) {
            echoCount();
        }
    }
}
```

By using `i % 100 == 0` you're checking if `i` is divisible by 100 without rest value. If that's the case, it means that you have ran 100 times 10ms which is 1000ms which is 1s. So you will output your `echoCountt()` every second.

This is an okay way to use threads. But your thread will keep running until it has counted to 10000000 seconds.

*On a sidenote, you should use 'i' instead of 'x' in for loops. It's more widely used like this and will be easier to read for experienced java developers*

Comment: Yes I know lol, but that's OP's problem, not mine ^^ I mentioned it in my answer that his thread will keep looping for a very long time. Maybe that's what he wants? I don't know.

Comment: :D the loading screen will be forever ^^

Comment: I think OP wants to continue increasing the counter every 10ms (or actually perform an operation of unknown duration) but only show the output every 1s.

Comment: @MichaelLang that's correct. I just used counttoabillion as an example of something that would take a very long time instead of giving all my code to generate md5sums.

Comment: @JREN the problem with this method is that each md5sum generation takes about 20s, so if I put that into this code, it will only update on every 100th md5sum calculated! That's why I think I need a thread to do the update, and a simultaneous thread to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
    int sleep = 10; //ms
    int echo = 1000; //ms
    for (double x=0;x<1000000000;x++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        count = x;
        if((x*sleep % echo) == 0) {
            echoCount();
        }
    }
```

Option 2:

- Create a new Class to manage your counter, it should be able to add, reset and so on. You will have to make sure it's thread safe (writing new values in case you want to update from various threads).
- Make one thread that increases the counter in given intervals
- Make another thread that polls the current count in other given intervals and print.

Answer (score 1):

```
long last=0;
@Override
public void run() {     
    for (double x=0;x<1000000000;x++) {
        try {
            doWork();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        count = x;
        if((System.currentTimeMillis()-last)>=1000) //post every second
        {
            last=System.currentTimeMillis();
            echoCount();
        }
    }       
}
```

This will print the count once every second assuming "work" does not take more than a second.

Comment: The problem is that each md5sum generation takes ~20s, hence I think I need threads. Perhaps my counting example wasn't good, I should have just used a single task that takes 20s.

Comment: yes, so then you need to have one thread which checks the queue to see what .size it is (and print out the result every second), then 2xcpu threads which pull work from the synchronized queue, process it and push it to processed-queue.